# Ch++” or “ch+1” in C++?

Tags: c++, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

```
char ch;    
cin.get(ch);    
cout << ch+1;
```

Почему `cout` думает что `ch` - это `int` ? А в случае `++ch` нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ключевыми моментами здесь является то, что

1. По-определению, выражение `++ch` эквивалентно выражению `ch = ch + 1`.
2. Все целочисленные арифметические вычисления в языке С++ делаются в типе `int` (или `unsigned int`) как минимум. Типы меньшего размера автоматически преобразуются к типу `int` еще до начала вычислений.

Все вычисления в выражении `ch + 1` делаются в типе `int` и результат этого выражения имеет тип `int`. Когда вы печатаете этот результат сразу - он интерпретируется, как значение типа `int`.

Выражение `++ch` эквивалентно выражению `ch = ch + 1`. Сначала вычисляется результат выражения `ch + 1` (который все так же будет иметь тип `int`), а затем он помещается обратно в переменную `ch`. Сама сама переменная `ch` становится результатом всего выражения `++ch`. Тип значения при этом становится `char`.